# Show that for every $n \in \Bbb N$ there are at least $\log_2 \log_2 (n+1)$ prime numbers between 1 and $n$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question**
Show that for  every $n \in \Bbb  N$ there are at least $\log_2 \log_2 (n+1)$ prime numbers between 1 and $n$.

**Proof**
We only studied the prime number limit, and I can't see how to use it here. Also tried induction but I get stuck in the inductive step because I don't know how use the induction hypothesis in this case.

Would like some assistance (first week number theory difficulties...)

Comment: Have you heard about Euclid algorithm ?

Comment: yes. How do I use it here?

Comment: look for proof of Euclid

Comment: I can't even figure how this is related to the problem. From what I figure, maybe between n and n+1 there are more primes, but I don't know how many are there. Also I know that if one of the 2 nums is prime then gcd(a,b)=1.